# Google Chrome's status bar complete

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm Google Chrome user, but I don't like the *format* Chrome's status bar. Exactly, I want to see the full URL, not shorten.

How I can change that boundary imposed by GC Web browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, short of editing the browsers code. Submit the suggestion to the Chromium team and maybe they'll add the option. However, no extension can do this (at least, not yet) and you can't change it in a setting.

Comment: Thanks for the soon response.